# Why am I unable to scrape values from a Hidden tooltip of a Highchart using selenium python?

Tags: python, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, lxml

I've particularly asked a couple of questions on the same topic before asking it one final time.
To begin with, I am scraping values from https://www.similarweb.com/website/zalando.de/#overview

I am trying to scrape the contents from a graph. Take a look at this highchart graph.
[image]

I want to scrape value like its value as : 27,100,000. from the hidden tooltip. At present I am able to scrape the Months as [Nov '20,....Apr '21], However, I am unable to scrape its values.

Here's my complete code:

```
def website_monitoring():
    websites = ['https://www.similarweb.com/website/zalando.de/#overview']

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    for crawler in websites:
        browser.get(crawler)
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

        website_names = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/section[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a').get_attribute("href")
        total_visits = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span[2]/span[1]').text

        tooltip = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[local-name() = 'svg']/*[local-name()='g'][8]/*[local-name()='text']")))
        ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(tooltip).perform()
        month_value = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[local-name() = 'svg']/*[local-name()='g' and @class='highcharts-tooltip']/*[local-name()='text']")))
        values = [elem.text for elem in month_value]
        print('VALUES-->', values)
        months = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[local-name() = 'svg']/*[local-name()='g'][6]/*/*")
        for date in months:
            print(date.text)

        # printing all scraped data
        print('Website Names:', website_names)
        print('Total visits:', total_visits)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    website_monitoring()
```

The output that I presently get:

```
VALUES--> ['']
Nov '20
Dec '20
Jan '21
Feb '21
Mar '21
Apr '21
```

The output that I want:

```
VALUES--> ['27,100,000', .....]
Nov '20
Dec '20
Jan '21
Feb '21
Mar '21
Apr '21
```

I am stuck on this issue since 2 days and nothing sofar has worked upon trying. Please, Please help!

**EDIT**: I also tried a method to check if a csv file exists upon inspecting the page and then going to the networks tab as Highcharts graph usually store a csv file but I Guess the site has blocked it. Is this possible by using a json or lxml?

Comment: This question is not related to using the Highcharts library.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel the graph is using highcharts, hence I added it in the comments. Do you have an idea of how to get the values from the graph?

Comment: From Highcharts perspective, you can get the tooltip hover data in the formatter callback which triggers when the tooltip is rendered: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: This task cannot be solved easily. How would I solve it (I actually tried with no luck because of the lack of time).1 . Move to the upper left corner of the chart to get the first tooltip 2. Move to the right with offset to the the next tooltip and son on. I would wait till this tooltip appears on each node.  ` ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).perform()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution that works. I took the time to identify a way to hover over each of the points, print the data, and move to the next.  This could be way cleaner, but it works.  Here's my python file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time



def website_monitoring():
    chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

    websites = ['https://www.similarweb.com/website/zalando.de/#overview']

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('start-maximized')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def stringToPrint():
        return browser.find_element_by_css_selector('g.highcharts-tooltip > text > tspan:nth-child(1)').text + ': ' + browser.find_element_by_css_selector('tspan:nth-child(3)').text

    for crawler in websites:
        browser.get(crawler)
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

        website_names = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/section[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a').get_attribute("href")
        total_visits = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span[2]/span[1]').text

        highchartElement = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'g:nth-child(8) > path:nth-child(3)')))

        ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(highchartElement).move_by_offset(-300,0).perform()
        print(stringToPrint())
        ActionChains(browser).move_by_offset(120,-10).perform()
        print(stringToPrint())
        ActionChains(browser).move_by_offset(120,0).perform()
        print(stringToPrint())
        ActionChains(browser).move_by_offset(120,-10).perform()
        print(stringToPrint())
        ActionChains(browser).move_by_offset(120,10).perform()
        print(stringToPrint())
        ActionChains(browser).move_by_offset(120,0).perform()
        print(stringToPrint())

        # printing all scraped data
        print('Website Names:', website_names)
        print('Total visits:', total_visits)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    website_monitoring()
```

And here's the console output:

```
November, 2020: 29,900,000
December, 2020: 27,100,000
January, 2020: 26,900,000
February, 2021: 22,600,000
March, 2021: 24,700,000
April, 2021: 26,200,000
Website Names: http://zalando.de/
Total visits: 19.94M
```

Comment: You are a genius man, this works just the way I wanted it to. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: just a small question, how did you select which the offset values like (120,0), (120, 10), (120, -10), (-300, 0) ?

Comment: Trial and error. I found that the `highchartElement` element I am targeting was vertically even with the first bullet to hover. I tried moving like `-250,0`, then added a `context_click()` to the `actionChain` to see exactly where the pointer was. With trial and error I found the above values work.

Comment: Got it..so for the rest of the sites like "https://www.similarweb.com/website/adidas.com/#overview" The ActionChains would be different..

Comment: Oh, yes, unfortunately. I bet it is possible to look at the graph to automatically identify the points to hover, but that sounds hard.